# Как зашифровать в Swift-е, RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding?

Tags: java, swift, криптография, rsa

Всем привет! Помогите, как правильно зашифровать в Swift-е

```
 private static byte[] cipher(byte[] tlvCardData, PublicKey publicKey) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(tlvCardData);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new CardEncryptException("failed to encrypt", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогло стандартное SecPadding.PKCS1

```
private func encrypt(buffer: [UInt8], publicKey: SecKey) -> String? {
        var keySize   = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey)
        var keyBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)
        
        // Encrypto  should less than key length
        guard SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &keyBuffer, &keySize) == errSecSuccess else { return nil }
        
        return Data(bytes: keyBuffer, count: keySize).base64EncodedString()
    }
```